# Is my guess on the behavior of the "Users" page correct?

Tags: discussion, design

When I go to my own reputation page, which has several different display modes (by post, by time, graph), it will default to whatever my last choice was. Same with activity, favorites, etc.

Other tabs default to something specific: the Badges tab seems to default to "all" and "General"; the Tags tab to "popular".

When I click on the Users tab, though, and it defaults to the "Reputation" display, sometimes I'm shown the "Week" total, sometimes the "Month" total, sometimes the "Quarter" total, etc.

I noticed today that it was showing me the Quarter total; I also noticed that I am listed first in the Quarter, Yearly, and All total, fourth in the Monthly total, and second in the Weekly total.

I'm guessing that the timeframe it defaults to is the one in which I'm ranked highest, with ties being broken in favor of the "shortest" timeframe. Is this correct?

**Update.** Well, my guess is definitely incorrect; right now I am being defaulted to the "Week" view, which is not my highest ranking. I wonder how it decides what to default to?

Comment: Do you refer to the Users page on meta or main? Currently there are  rep-related changes being rolled out first to meta, which may explain temporary differences between the sites. I too am currently brought to the Quarter view by default (but that's *not* where I am highest ranked).

Comment: Was there a timeframe which is longer than two days, in which you're not the highest rank user? :-)

Comment: @Bill: I'm talking about the Main site. Yesterday, I was being put in the Weekly page; often, early in the week, I seem to be brought to other defalts. I'm not really worried about difference between rep totals in meta and in the main site; I'm just curiuous about why it defaults me to a particular time-frame view.

Comment: @Arturo I've seen the same inconsistency in defaults. Btw, did you too just get a bunch of unupvotes? Perhaps someone recently left?

Comment: @Asaf: Certainly: I've been trailing Brian Scott almost all this week... (-: